# 2 ng-clicks calling same function in ng-repeat Ionic AngularJs

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-click

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j2JX5.png)

We have Plus and Minus buttons inside ng-repeat. Each button should increment or decrement value inside the particular textbox. There are 2 functions for increment and decrement whatever the button clicked only one event is firing. Though both the buttons have different function names.

[image]

Here is my controller code using to fire the event

```
    app.controller('MultiCheckOutCtrl',function($ionicPlatform,$ionicHistory,$rootScope,$scope,$state,$http,webservices,myconfig,$ionicPopup,$ionicLoading){
console.clear();
 $rootScope.$ionicGoBack = function(backCount) {
$ionicHistory.goBack(backCount);
//alert("back button");
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("hide");
};
$ionicPlatform.registerBackButtonAction(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker("hide");
$ionicHistory.goBack();
}, 100);
    // increment for + button //
   $ionicLoading.show({
      template: "Please Wait."
   });
    $scope.decrement = function(){
      alert("decrement");
    }//end of decrement
    $scope.increment = function(){
      alert("increment");          
    }
  $scope.userBookingDetails = {};
  $scope.usrdata={};
  $scope.errorStatus=false;         webservices.getPackagesBasedOnResortId($scope.resortid).success(function(data) {
        //console.log("Inside MultiCheckOutCtrl controller : "+data[0].bannerimage); 
        $scope.userBookingDetails = data;
        //console.clear();
        //console.log(data);
        $ionicLoading.hide();
    });      
});
```

Here is my view file:

```
`<div class="card" ng-repeat="r in userBookingDetails">
  <div class="list" >
    <div class="item item-divider">
      {{r.packagename}}
    </div>
    <label class="item item-input">
      <div class="input-label col col-30">
        Adults (Per Ticket) <span>Rs. {{r.adultprice}} </span>
      </div>
      <div class="input-label col col-20">
        <button class="button  button-calm mybtn" ng-click="decrement()">
            -
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="input-label col col-30">
        <input type="text" class="qty" /> 
      </div>
      <div class="input-label col col-20">
         <button class="button  button-calm mybtn" ng-click="increment()">
            +
        </button>
      </div>
    </label>
    <label class="item item-input" ng-if="r.childprice!=0">
      <div class="input-label col col-80">
        Children (Per Ticket) <span>Rs. {{r.childprice}}  </span>
      </div>
      <input type="number" name=""  ng-model="userBookingDetails[$index].mobilechildqty" placeholder="0" value="0" class="col col-20" side="right" style="float:right;" >
    </label>
  </div>
</div>`
```

Comment: which event is firing?  are you saying that if you click on either the + or -, they both call the same function?

Comment: Hi Thanks in advance, $scope.decrement is firing

Comment: that's odd.  Not sure if it is the bug, but you are missing the `;` after both `$scope.increment = ...` and `$scope.decrement = ...`.  Remember that these are assignment statements - which are different than plain function declarations.